# How do I use a Condvar without moving the Mutex variable?

Tags: rust, condition-variable

I want to use a `Condvar` in my program. Below is a short test of it. I know it will be stuck forever on the loop.

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Condvar, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let var_in_lock = Arc::new(Mutex::new(8));
    let cvar = Arc::new(Condvar::new());

    let unlocked = var_in_lock.lock().unwrap();

    loop {
        cvar.wait(unlocked).unwrap();
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `unlocked`
  --> src/main.rs:10:19
   |
7  |     let unlocked = var_in_lock.lock().unwrap();
   |         -------- move occurs because `unlocked` has type `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
10 |         cvar.wait(unlocked).unwrap();
   |                   ^^^^^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

I have looked at [the example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html#method.wait) in the Rust documentation. The two differences I spot are:

1. They create the `Condvar` and `Mutex` in a pair. This shouldn't matter, right? I want to create them separately.
2. They match the lock using the `ref` keyword, which, if I understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285560/in-function-parameters-what-is-the-difference-between-using-the-ref-keyword-and) answer correctly, means that a reference to the lock is made. I figured that by changing the line to `cvar.wait(&unlocked).unwrap();` would be the same thing, but then the compiler complains that a `MutexGuard`, and not a reference, is expected.

How can I make it compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference that you *didn't* spot is that `wait` returns the `MutexGuard`:

```
pub fn wait<'a, T>(
    &self,
    guard: MutexGuard<'a, T>
) -> LockResult<MutexGuard<'a, T>>
```

```
while !*started {
    started = cvar.wait(started).unwrap();
}
```

`wait` takes ownership of the `MutexGuard` since it releases the lock and later reacquires it. Transferring ownership statically prevents using an improperly locked (or unlocked) variable, an example of using Rust's type system to the programmers advantage.

---

You need to do the same thing in your code:

```
let mut unlocked = var_in_lock.lock().unwrap();

loop {
    unlocked = cvar.wait(unlocked).unwrap();
}
```

See also:

- [How do I use a Condvar to limit multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29870837/155423)
- [Buffer in Rust with Mutex and Condvar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47554092/155423)

Comment: So `wait()` needs to take ownership of `MutexGuard` while waiting and then it hands it back?